Long running slurm job starting separate slurm jobs
I have a long running program (program A) that writes to a file periodically.
I have a separate program (program B) that I need to run whenever that file is updated.
Is it possible to create a slurm job that executes the main program and which will spin off new slurm job as and when the file gets updated?


Do you have a script to invoke B when needed?  If you do, then it should be a simple matter to invoke B with sbatch. I don't think there is anything in slurm to detect file changes, you have to do that on your own.

I do but process B requires substantial resources, as such I don't want to have a job that is sitting on the resources doing nothing for most of the time while waiting for A to update the file.

If you already have a script that does program B and have a way to execute it during program A you should be wrap sbatch around it and periodically submit the job from A instead of running it directly. You may want to check for similar jobs with squeue before each sbatch to make sure they are not piling up.
